# Inline keyboard conflict

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Good afternoon, I'm making a python bot in the aiogram library. Faced a problem, I created two inline keyboards and I have two menu buttons, one button should call the first inline keyboard and the second the second. But at startup it turns out that only the keyboard that is called first in the code is called, that is, in my code, "inline_button_menu" is called first, and the second does not react anymore. Help solve the problem.
Here is my code:

```
# Создание кнопок инлайн ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

```
inline_btn_1 = InlineKeyboardButton('Сьогодні', callback_data='btn1')
inline_btn_2 = InlineKeyboardButton('На неділі', callback_data='btn2')
inline_btn_3 = InlineKeyboardButton('У цьому місяці', callback_data='btn3')

inline_btn_4 = InlineKeyboardButton('Останні 3 новини', callback_data='btn4')
inline_btn_5 = InlineKeyboardButton('Свіжі новини', callback_data='btn5')

# Инициализация кнопок(инлайн) ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


inline_button_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(
    inline_btn_1).add(inline_btn_2).add(inline_btn_3)

inline_button_menu_2 = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(
    inline_btn_4).add(inline_btn_5)


# Кнопки меню(инлайн) ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@dp.message_handler()
async def menu_birthday(message: types.Message):
    # await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, message.text)
    if message.text == 'Дні народження':
        await message.reply("Виберіть як подивитися дні народження: ", 
        reply_markup=inline_button_menu)

@dp.message_handler()
async def menu_news(message: types.Message):
    # await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, message.text)
    if message.text == 'Новини':
        await message.reply("Виберіть як подивитися новини: ", 
        reply_markup=inline_button_menu_2)



@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'btn4') # --------------------------- Последние три новости
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    with open("news_dict.json") as file:
        news_dict = json.load(file)

    for k, v in sorted(news_dict.items())[-3:]:
        news = f"{hlink(v['article_title'], v['article_url'])}"

        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, news)

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'btn5') # --------------------------- Свежие новости
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    fresh_news = check_news_update()

    if len(fresh_news) >= 1:
        for k, v in sorted(fresh_news.items()):
            news = f"{hlink(v['article_title'], v['article_url'])}"

            await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, news)

    else:
        await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'Свіжих новин немає')

@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'btn1') # -------------------------------------- Дни рождения
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, 'Day: ')
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late, but

in your code there are two message handlers without any filters, so all your messages handled by this handler:

> async def menu_birthday(message: types.Message):

For example you could add second condition to first function:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def menu_birthday(message: types.Message):
    if message.text == 'Дні народження':
        await message.reply("Виберіть як подивитися дні народження: ", 
        reply_markup=inline_button_menu)
    elif message.text == 'Новини':
        await message.reply("Виберіть як подивитися новини: ", 
        reply_markup=inline_button_menu_2)
```

or you could have 2 separate handlers with **text** filters like this:

```
@dp.message_handler(text='Дні народження')
async def menu_birthday(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Виберіть як подивитися дні народження: ", reply_markup=inline_button_menu)
    
@dp.message_handler(text='Новини')
async def menu_news(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Виберіть як подивитися новини: ", reply_markup=inline_button_menu_2)
```